# Cant create Event Hub in Brazil South Region

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Actually I cannot create a Service Bus - Event Hub in Brazil South Region with the error: Fail to create the event hub 'XYZ'. No further info.

All my other services are running fine, no errors at all. My only problem is with the Event Hub creation.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually also experiencing the same now in North Europe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We hit a provisioning bug in brazil region and it is now resolved. Please retry the operation and it will work.